# What is the correct MS Access SQL syntax for creating a union query

Tags: sql, ms-access

The Microsoft documentation states:

`CREATE VIEW view [(field1[, field2[, ...]])] AS selectstatement`

and lists a number of provisions. I am trying to create a union query with the `CREATE VIEW` statement using `ADODB`. The union itself I can run in Access (2013) and save (it shows it is saved as a union query with the two little interlocked circles icon). But the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 engine complains either `Unions` not allowed in a subquery or  Only simple `SELECT` queries are allowed in `VIEWS`. Do I need to use `DAO` or is there a different syntax? My create view statement is:

```sql
uString = "CREATE VIEW vwSpendingTotals (Spending, Name) as SELECT Spending, Name FROM " & _
" (SELECT  Sum( tblA.Amount) as Spending, 'Auto' as Name from tblGeneral_Ledger  gl " & _
" inner join tblAccount_AUTO as tblA on gl.Trans_ID = tblA.Trans_ID " & _
" where gl.Debit_Credit < 0 AND Trans_Date > DateSerial(Year(Now()),1,1)  Union " & _
" SELECT  Sum( tblH.Amount) as Spending, 'Household' as Name from tblGeneral_Ledger  gl " & _
" inner join tblAccount_Household as tblH on gl.Trans_ID = tblH.Trans_ID " & _
" where gl.Debit_Credit < 0 AND Trans_Date > DateSerial(Year(Now()),1,1) union " & _
" SELECT  Sum( tblL.Amount) as Spending, 'Living' as Name from tblGeneral_Ledger  gl " & _
" inner join tblAccount_Living as tblL on gl.Trans_ID = tblL.Trans_ID " & _
" where gl.Debit_Credit < 0 AND Trans_Date > DateSerial(Year(Now()),1,1)  union " & _
" SELECT  Sum( tblM.Amount) as Spending, 'Medical' as Name from tblGeneral_Ledger  gl " & _
" inner join tblAccount_Medical as tblM on gl.Trans_ID = tblM.Trans_ID " & _
" where gl.Debit_Credit < 0 AND Trans_Date > DateSerial(Year(Now()),1,1) union " & _
" SELECT  Sum( tblP.Amount) as Spending, 'Personal' as Name from tblGeneral_Ledger  gl " & _
" inner join tblAccount_Personal as tblP on gl.Trans_ID = tblP.Trans_ID " & _
" where gl.Debit_Credit < 0 AND Trans_Date > DateSerial(Year(Now()),1,1) union " & _
" SELECT  Sum( tblU.Amount) as Spending, 'Utilities' as Name from tblGeneral_Ledger  gl " & _
" inner join tblAccount_Utilities as tblU on gl.Trans_ID = tblU.Trans_ID " & _
" where gl.Debit_Credit < 0 AND Trans_Date > DateSerial(Year(Now()),1,1)) order by Name"
objConnection.Execute uString
```

`objConnection` has been instantiated a little earlier in the script.
Should the Microsoft documentation be updated to reflect the error being returned by the Jet 12 engine or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Thanks in advance,
Harold

Comment: Format(<br>)? Make subqueries views to circumvent Error (Unions not allowed in a subquery)!

Comment: That is a possibility worth pursuing

Comment: Yep, that seems to be the only palatable way to do it. I can construct and execute pretty sophisticated unions and fairly nested joins against an Access database using the ucanaccess 4.0 library and in the Access Query design SQL window, But Access is a real weinie when it comes to creating views. Nested joins have to be broken down into a series of inter-dependent views Thanks for the direction

Answer (score 0):

Have you run it with an alias after your subquery:

```
uString = "CREATE VIEW vwSpendingTotals (Spending, Name) as SELECT Spending, Name FROM " & _
" (SELECT  Sum( tblA.Amount) as Spending, 'Auto' as Name from tblGeneral_Ledger  gl " & _
" inner join tblAccount_AUTO as tblA on gl.Trans_ID = tblA.Trans_ID " & _
" where gl.Debit_Credit < 0 AND Trans_Date > DateSerial(Year(Now()),1,1)  Union " & _
" SELECT  Sum( tblH.Amount) as Spending, 'Household' as Name from tblGeneral_Ledger  gl " & _
" inner join tblAccount_Household as tblH on gl.Trans_ID = tblH.Trans_ID " & _
" where gl.Debit_Credit < 0 AND Trans_Date > DateSerial(Year(Now()),1,1) union " & _
" SELECT  Sum( tblL.Amount) as Spending, 'Living' as Name from tblGeneral_Ledger  gl " & _
" inner join tblAccount_Living as tblL on gl.Trans_ID = tblL.Trans_ID " & _
" where gl.Debit_Credit < 0 AND Trans_Date > DateSerial(Year(Now()),1,1)  union " & _
" SELECT  Sum( tblM.Amount) as Spending, 'Medical' as Name from tblGeneral_Ledger  gl " & _
" inner join tblAccount_Medical as tblM on gl.Trans_ID = tblM.Trans_ID " & _
" where gl.Debit_Credit < 0 AND Trans_Date > DateSerial(Year(Now()),1,1) union " & _
" SELECT  Sum( tblP.Amount) as Spending, 'Personal' as Name from tblGeneral_Ledger  gl " & _
" inner join tblAccount_Personal as tblP on gl.Trans_ID = tblP.Trans_ID " & _
" where gl.Debit_Credit < 0 AND Trans_Date > DateSerial(Year(Now()),1,1) union " & _
" SELECT  Sum( tblU.Amount) as Spending, 'Utilities' as Name from tblGeneral_Ledger  gl " & _
" inner join tblAccount_Utilities as tblU on gl.Trans_ID = tblU.Trans_ID " & _
" where gl.Debit_Credit < 0 AND Trans_Date > DateSerial(Year(Now()),1,1))a order by Name"
objConnection.Execute uString
```

Comment: As I understand the concept of a union, each subquery equates to a row in the result set and each subquery must contain the same number and names of columns. Aliasing the subqueries would be useful for a join statement but I am not sure how it would facilitate the union. The point is that in Access, in the query design, SQL view, I can enter all the above SQL and run and save the query (which is saved as a union) and query from that saved query (in reality a view) but the create view mechanism doesn't accommodate my wishes. Works in Oracle, SQLServer, etc. just not MS Access